# What equivalent in Docker.DotNet (NET CORE) docker parameters --expose=[] and -p=[]

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I try to use NET CORE package https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet to start docker container from NET CORE.
Usually my command line looks as

```
sudo docker run -it \
--name digiwage.$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S) \
--expose='46003' \
-p '157.XX.XX.85:46003:46003' \
 XXXXXX/daemon:latest
```

following docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports docker has are two parameters related to port

```
--expose=[] Expose a port or a range of ports inside the container
-p=[] Publish a container's port or a range of ports to the host
```

First one is docker exposed port list, second one is ports publishing to docker host. This is different meaning, for example docker host can have a lot of IP address and we need to publish port only to one IP.

I try to start container in this way

```
    Dim ExposedPorts = New Dictionary(Of String, EmptyStruct)
    ExposedPorts.Add("157.XX.XX.85:46004:46004", New EmptyStruct)
    Dim Prm = New CreateContainerParameters With {
                  .Image = "alexev275/digiwage:latest",
                  .Name = $"digiwage.{Guid.NewGuid}",
                  .Env = New List(Of String),
                  .ExposedPorts = ExposedPorts,
                  .Tty = True
    }
```

and see in console zero as docker port parameters

[image]

I have expected two parameters related to port in CreateContainerParameters, but no, second parameters is absent.

[image]

Comment: Commented on your Github issue

Answer (score 1):

I found workable solution.

[image]

```
    Dim ExposedPorts = New Dictionary(Of String, EmptyStruct)
    Dim ContainerPort = "46003"
    ExposedPorts.Add(ContainerPort, New EmptyStruct)

    Dim OneHostBinding As New PortBinding With {.HostIP = "157.XX.XX.86", .HostPort = "46003"}
    Dim HostBindingList As New List(Of PortBinding)
    HostBindingList.Add(OneHostBinding)
    Dim PortBindings As New Dictionary(Of String, IList(Of PortBinding))
    PortBindings.Add("46003", HostBindingList)

    Dim Labels = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Labels.Add("TstKey", "TstVal")
    Dim CMD = New List(Of String)
    CMD.Add("pwd")
    Dim Prm = New CreateContainerParameters With {
                  .Image = "alexev275/digiwage:latest",
                  .Name = $"digiwage.{Guid.NewGuid}",
                  .Env = Env,
                  .ExposedPorts = ExposedPorts,
                  .Labels = Labels,
                  .Tty = True,
                  .HostConfig = New HostConfig With {.PortBindings = PortBindings}
    }
```